# Keras RNN (R) text generation word level model

Tags: r, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've been working through the example for character-level text generation : https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/lstm_text_generation.html

I'm having trouble extending this example to a word-level model. See reprex below

```
library(keras)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tokenizers)

# Parameters

maxlen <- 40

# Data Preparation

# Retrieve text
path <- get_file(
  'nietzsche.txt', 
  origin='https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/nietzsche.txt'
  )

# Load, collapse, and tokenize text
text <- read_lines(path) %>%
  str_to_lower() %>%
  str_c(collapse = "\n") %>%
  tokenize_words( simplify = TRUE)

print(sprintf("corpus length: %d", length(text)))

words <- text %>%
  unique() %>%
  sort()

print(sprintf("total words: %d", length(words)))
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "corpus length: 101345"
[1] "total words: 10283"
```

When I move on to the next step I run into issues:

```
# Cut the text in semi-redundant sequences of maxlen characters
dataset <- map(
  seq(1, length(text) - maxlen - 1, by = 3), 
  ~list(sentece = text[.x:(.x + maxlen - 1)], next_char = text[.x + maxlen])
  )

dataset <- transpose(dataset)

# Vectorization
X <- array(0, dim = c(length(dataset$sentece), maxlen, length(words)))
y <- array(0, dim = c(length(dataset$sentece), length(words)))

for(i in 1:length(dataset$sentece)){

  X[i,,] <- sapply(words, function(x){
    as.integer(x == dataset$sentece[[i]])
  })

  y[i,] <- as.integer(words == dataset$next_char[[i]])

}


Error: cannot allocate vector of size 103.5 Gb
```

Now compared to the character example I have a lot more words than I did characters in the vocabulary, which is probably why I'm running into vector size issues, but how would I go about pre-processing the word level text data to fit into a rnn? Is this done somehow through the embedding layer? Do I need to do some removal of stop words/stemming to get the word vocabulary down?

**Edit:** I'm still looking for a solution to this issue, but below gives some additional background and ideas: https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/161

Answer (score 0):

I think [this article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-word-level-neural-language-model-in-keras/) might be useful to you, though it approaches it a bit differently than you do, specifically:

- They use the [Keras Tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) to tokenize the text
- They use the [to_categorical](https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#:%7E:text=to_categorical) function to turn the tokens into one-hot-encoded vectors.

Even then, when I did it with a larger dataset, I also had memory issues when I tried to process a lot of items at once, so I had to break it down into small chunks and train it that way.